# Highlight first mismatching paren

Tags: emacs

Rainbow-delimiters is a nice library for showing matching parens.  It has the nice property that if you have extra right parens, it will color them in some loud color.

e.g. in `(  ))`  the second `)` will show up red.  I would love it if the other direction worked too.  I.e., `(( )` showed the first paren bright red.  Is there any way to tweak rainbow-delimiters to do this, or some other package that I could use to do so?

Comment: This package seems to work with your second example, but not your first example:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightParentheses

Comment: @ seanmcl: Could you test the code from my answer below, please. When we have tested it for a week or so evaluating it as useful we could contact the maintainer of the rainbow-delimiters package and ask whether he could add this feature optionally. I tested some large scale elisp-file. But, I think more tests are required before we can ask him.

Comment: Sure.  I'll try it out and let you know.  Thanks.

Comment: I already noted that it is important to have `(jit-mode t)` and stelth font lock activated. Else the following problem occurs. Let us assume you have a large balanced source-code file. Add an open delimiter at the beginning. That will be marked as unmatching. If you then add a matching closing delimiter at the end the closing delimiter will be correctly colored as matching but the opening delimiter keeps marked as unmatching. If the user does not edit again at the beginning of the file the marking of the opening delimiter can only be corrected by `jit-lock-stealth-fontify`.

Comment: Interesting.   Have you noticed emacs using more cpu with rainbow-delimiters on?  My emacs has so many packages running I can't tell what's slowing mine down, and I haven't had the heart to binary search for the culprit yet.

Comment: Emacs is supposed to do some font-locking after `jit-lock-stealth-time`. But, for me that is 1% of cpu for a 103k elisp file with `rainbow-delimiters` on. And elisp files have some nested parenthesis in it, you know;-).

Comment: Nice.  Thanks for this.  I'm normally leery of advice, but this seems better than hacking rainbow-delimiters for the time being.  Thanks for this!

Comment: For the record, this works just fine.  I've been using it constantly for 2 weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem is that it is not clear or rather difficult to decide which opening delimiter is wrong and has to be highlighted. Note, that in the example `(()` the first or the second parenthesis could be wrong. It might be that the third parenthesis closes the second one and the closing parenthesis for the first one is missing or it could be that the first matches the third and the closing for the second is missing.

There follows a dirty hack for `rainbow-delimiters` that highlights the first opening delimiter in the region offered by `jit-lock` if `scan-sexps` gives an error for this delimiter. The guess work for the wrong delimiter can be wrong. But, maybe the hack is better than nothing.

```
(defadvice rainbow-delimiters-propertize-region (after hack-unmatching-open activate)
  "Also mark unmatching open delimiters. Fast fragile hack, not regarding type of delimiter."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char start)
    (while (and
        (< (point) end)
        (re-search-forward "[[{(]" end t)) ;;< first opening delimiter within region
      (let ((pos (1- (point)))) ;; Note, syntax-ppss does shift position anyway. So, avoiding this does not make sense.
    (unless (save-excursion (rainbow-delimiters-char-ineligible-p pos))
      (condition-case err
          (goto-char (scan-sexps pos 1))
        (scan-error
         (rainbow-delimiters-apply-color (cdr (assoc (char-before) '((?\( . "paren") (?\[ . "bracket") (?\{ . "brace")))) -1 pos))))))))
```

EDIT: I have included `scan-sexps` in the test and removed the depths test at end of file. I've got the impression that improves the behaviour a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion from Tobias seems to target a considerably earlier version of `rainbow-delimiters`.  I'm not sure if has much bearing on recent versions.

Here is a solution that comes very close to solving the stated problem by using the `highlight-parentheses` package as well as `rainbow-delimiters`.  You can save this code and test it with:

> `emacs -Q -l ~/debug-rainbow-delimiters.el -f emacs-lisp-mode`

```
(setq debug-on-error t)

(when (>= emacs-major-version 24)
  (require 'package)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives 
               '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
  (package-initialize)
  )

(require 'highlight-parentheses)

(setq hl-paren-colors '("dodger blue"))

(set-face-attribute 'hl-paren-face nil
                    :foreground 'unspecified
                    :inherit 'show-paren-mismatch)

(require 'paren)
(require 'rainbow-delimiters)
(set-face-attribute 'rainbow-delimiters-unmatched-face nil
                    :foreground 'unspecified
                    :inherit 'show-paren-mismatch)

(defvar my-paren-colors '("dodger blue"))

(setq rainbow-delimiters-max-face-count 1)

(set-face-foreground 'rainbow-delimiters-depth-1-face (elt my-paren-colors 1))

;; Hook the above into various Lisp modes

(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook 'highlight-parentheses)
(add-hook 'lisp-interaction-mode-hook 'highlight-parentheses)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'highlight-parentheses-mode)
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'highlight-parentheses-mode)

(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
(add-hook 'lisp-interaction-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)

;;; Custom

(custom-set-variables
   '(package-selected-packages
     '(highlight-parentheses rainbow-delimiters)))
```

The solution isn't perfect -- matching depends on the position of the cursor.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

**You can confuse it:**

[image]

---

**Perhaps most importantly, it has the side effect of highlighting one level of surrounding parentheses at all times:**

[image]

---

My personal assessment is that this is likely to be very helpful **(** and it would be nice if there was a somewhat more sophisticated solution! **)**